# underwater mosaic with overlapping photos

Tags: mosaic, mosaic-dataset, atmospheric-correction

What is the best approach to creating a mosaic with underwater photos.

The photos are black and white. They suffer from non-uniform illumination, i.e. the middle of the photo is bright and the edges are black. My attempts creating a mosaic with such photos result in a mosaic with stripes marks.

An example of an ideal result is attached.

Left : before and right : after

[image: before and after]

AUV, underwater, illumination-correction